# How to group DataFrame by two columns and create two new columns with min and max values from third column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the DataFrame:

```
a = [{'column_1': 'A', 'column_2': 'B', 'column_3': 3},
     {'column_1': 'A', 'column_2': 'B', 'column_3': 8},
     {'column_1': 'Y', 'column_2': 'C', 'column_3': 2},
     {'column_1': 'Y', 'column_2': 'C', 'column_3': 10},
     {'column_1': 'Y', 'column_2': 'C', 'column_3': 6},
     {'column_1': 'F', 'column_2': 'S', 'column_3': 11},
     {'column_1': 'F', 'column_2': 'S', 'column_3': 18},
     {'column_1': 'F', 'column_2': 'S', 'column_3': 5},
     {'column_1': 'F', 'column_2': 'S', 'column_3': 20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

I need to group a DataFrame by columns `df['column_1']` and `df['column_2']`, create two new columns `df['min']` and `df['max']`, insert the **min** and **max** values from column `df['column_3']`

I need the next result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'], as_index=False)['column_3'].agg({'min':'min', 'max':'max'})
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes, this option gives a result, but not exactly the one that I indicated in the screenshot, df['min'] and df['max'] i need as columns

Comment: I did this and this one works for me: df['column_4'] = df['column_3']
df1 = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'], as_index=False).agg({'column_3':'min', 'column_4':'max'})

Comment: @LiAfe you should also be able to write: `df1 = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'], as_index=False).agg({'min':'min', 'max':'max'})` which directly names them correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes it will work, with a little change: `df1 = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'], as_index=False).column_3.agg({'min':'min', 'max':'max'})`

Comment: you are right, I didnt notice column 3, updated the answer